# Не устанавливается соединение с mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

Здравствуйте.

Есть несколько вопросов по Джанго.

1) На винде 7 под апачем поднял питон 3.4 + джанго 1.7, но не получается соединить все это с mysql (версия mysql 5.0.3.7).
Пробовал, как в этой [инструкции](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.ru/2014/09/django-with-python-3-and-mysql-database.html), выполнил команду `python manage.py. migrate` и получил ошибку:

> django.db.utils.no supported error
> aythentication with old passwords is
> not supported

Как это побороть?
Менял пароль в phpmyadmin на более сложный с цифрами, регистром и % ставил, но все равно не помогло ничего!

2) У меня питон 3.4, но программировать нужно на версии 2.7. Как поставить второй питон и под ним начать программировать на джанго, чтобы проект создался под питоном 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

**Пункт 1**.

- [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970545/mysql-workbench-error-authentication-with-old-insecure-passwords)
- [MysqlDocs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html)

**Пункт 2**.

Посмотрите вот эту ссылку [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv). Документация [здесь](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage).